# Google Maps 'heatmap' that can handle density AND data values?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, heatmap

I have locations that have quality 'X', where X can be a negative or positive value. I would like to plot negative values of X as red, and positive values as green. Intermediate values will be yellow. The opacity of the color will correspond to local density of data.

[Issue 85](http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/issues/detail?id=85) proves that fusion tables alone can't do this yet. Is there a viable extension that can handle this style of heatmapping?

I've made a mockup of what I want [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJ4cF.jpg).

I don't know if variable transparency will be an inherent problem. Would that even be possible for a Google Map overlay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed possible, though I was only able to solve this problem with custom heatmap code. [You can see the result here.](http://www.venicenoise.org/)

I hope to add the ability to handle both density and data values simultaneously in [this API I created](http://www.heatmaptool.com/). Keep checking.